# javascript done function without ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise, jqxhr

I want to make a function that supports `done` but without returning ajax.

```
function checkAndReturn(){
    if(global.id){
        return global.id; // the problem might be here 
    }else{
        return $.get("http://someurl.com",null,function(){...})
    }
}
```

Here `checkAndReturn.done(function(){...})` works if `global.id` is not available, but it is not working if `global.id` is available.

I think I should be returning any other object and box my data to that object to make my done work, maybe `xhr`?.

Comment: You need to know what you're expecting your method to return. In the second case (`$.get`) you're returning an xhr object. You need to either return the id in both cases, or cache the xhr object in a variable and return that the second time.

Comment: @nbrooks He cannot return the id in the second case, the call is asynchronous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should return a (resolved) [jQuery `Deferred`](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) object. The `jqXHR` object returned by jQuery's AJAX functions is derived from `Deferred` as well, so the "interface" of your function will be clean - your function will return a `Deferred` in any case.

You could do something like this (just an example, adapt it to your use case):

```
function checkAndReturn(){
    if (global.id){
        return $.Deferred().resolve(global.id);
    }
    else {
        return $.get("http://someurl.com", null, function(){...})
    }
}
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nRX6V/1/)

Comment: Just was about to add an example :). I will leave yours, it is very similar to mine.

Comment: you should return idXHR

Comment: Made it a little more compact.